# Is there a way in Krita to import an image without losing its layers

Tags: import, krita

I have two images and I want to combine them into one. With the option Layer > Import/Export > Import Layer I was able to import a Krita Image, but only as a single layer. But I'd like to preserve the layer structure of the imported image.

Is there a way to import one Krita image into another (or combine them in some other way) so that all layers of both images are preserved.

I'm using Krita 3.1.3.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Krita 3.1.3 has a bug in this regard. If you click on a paint layer last, the option for copying the selected layers is available (which is not the case, if the last layer is e.g. a group layer): `Layer` > `Copy Layer`. With this you are able to copy multiple layer over to another file and hence combine them into one image without loosing the layer structure.